# Creating a sequence with a specific string and varying numbers and letters

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

I need to create a single row with columns that have a shared string, vary by number, and share repeating letters. My desired output looks like:

```
SNP1a  SNP1b  SNP2a  SNP2b ... SNP3502a  SNP3502b
```

I am new to using unix/linux, so my attempts have been rather rudimentary. So far I have done:

```
seq -f "SNP%1g" 1 3502 > header
awk '{print;print;}' header > header2
```

So that `header2` is:

```
SNP1
SNP1
SNP2
SNP2
...
SNP3502
SNP3502
```

However, I am stuck on how to add an alternating `a` and `b` to each row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `bash` :

```
printf '%s ' SNP{1..3502}{a..b}
```

If the last trailing space is a problem wrap it in a function:

```bash
headers(){
    local pieces=( SNP{1..3052}{a..b} ) IFS=' '
    printf '%s' "${pieces[*]}" # add '\n' to get new line at the end
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the `zsh` shell:

```
() { print ${(j[  ])@}; } SNP{1..3502}{a,b}
```

Where:

- `SNP{1..3502}{a,b}` generates the list using brace expansion
- that's passed to anonymous function where the list is available in the `$@` aka `$argv` array
- we join the elements of the array with two spaces inbetween with the `j[  ]` parameter expansion flag
- and pass that to `print` which prints it.

From another shell:

```
zsh -c '() { print ${(j[  ])@}; } SNP{1..3502}{a,b}'
```

If your list of numbers, prefixes and suffixes are in separate arrays:

```
pre=( SNP )
num=( {1..3502} )
suf=( a b )
() { print ${(j[  ])@}; } $^pre$^num$^suf
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -le 'print join "  ", map {$n=$_; map "SNP$n$_", qw(a b)} (1..3502)'
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! If I run `() { print ${(j[  ])@}; } SNP{1..3502}{a,b}` or `zsh () { print ${(j[  ])@}; } SNP{1..3502}{a,b}`, I get the following error: `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token SNP{1...3502}{a,b}` (My apologies if I am missing something obvious here...)

Comment: @ZoeDiaz-Martin as stated in the answers this is zsh syntax. You should prefix Stephane function with something as ```/bin/zsh -c 'the function here'```, or open zsh shell in your terminal emulator.

Comment: @DanieleGrassini thank you for clarifying! I understand. I am constantly exposing my ignorance here - I should have specified in my post that I am using bash!

Comment: @ZoeDiaz-Martin no problem, we are all here to learn.

Answer (score 2):

With any of ksh, bash or zsh just use echo:

```
$ echo SNP{1..3502}{a,b}       # {a..b} also works here.
SNP1a SNP1b SNP2a SNP2b SNP3a SNP3b SNP4a SNP4b SNP5a .....
```

In this specific case `echo` is perfectly fine as there is no leading '-'on the generated list nor there are special characters inside.

If you must use `printf`, then try:

```
printf '%s\n' SNP{1..3}{a,b} | paste -s -d ' ' -
```

And, if you must use awk, then use [Ed Morton's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/706443/529738)

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
awk '
     BEGIN {
        n = split("a b", lets)
        for ( i=1; i <= 5; i++ ) {
            for ( j=1; j <= n; j++ ) {
                printf "%sSNP%d%s", sep, i, lets[j]
                sep = OFS
            }
        }
        print ""
    }
'
SNP1a SNP1b SNP2a SNP2b SNP3a SNP3b SNP4a SNP4b SNP5a SNP5b
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -e 'my  @nbr = "SNP" xx 3502 Z~ 1..3502; \
         for @nbr -> $i {put $i ~ "a"; put $i ~ "b"};'
```

OR

```perl
raku -e 'my @nbr = "SNP" xx 3502 Z~ 1..3502; my @ltr = "a".."b"; \
         for @nbr -> $i {put $i ~ @ltr[0]; put $i ~ @ltr[1]};'
```

OR

```perl
raku -e 'my @nbr = "SNP" xx 3502 Z~ 1..3502; my @ltr = "a".."b"; \
         for @nbr -> $i {put $i ~ $_ for @ltr};'
```

This no doubt can be improved, but it gets the job done. The code uses Raku's `Z` [infix operator](https://docs.raku.org/routine/Z), in conjunction with Raku's `~` (tilde) string-concatenation operator. Each identifier prints on a separate line. In the third example, `@ltr` letters load into `$_` (a.k.a. Raku's topic variable).

For more ideas on how to create sequences of identifier strings in Raku, see the SO link below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999523/concatenating-lists-in-raku?